# Reseed Primary Keys from all tables on a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I´m trying to reset the identity column of a few tables. The problem is that, these identity columns are used as a foreign keys in other tables, how can i do this?

Comment: As you've noticed yourself - this is a hell of a task - so **WHY** do you need to reseed at all?? Doing this properly is a major undertaking.... what's the need??

Answer (score 0):

Remove your table relationships.

And relate the tables again after re creating the identity columns of your tables.

Regards

Comment: If you set the FK entities to NULL, how do you propose to relate the tables back again?  Without using a cascaded update you at least need to keep an "old PK" field temporarily, so you can do an update on the FK fields.